# reducing time to take backup for virtual machines 376 Gb backup takes 4 hours to copy to USB

Tags: hard-drive, usb, backup, external-hard-drive, vmware-workstation

I have Workstation 15.0
I want to take its backup on an external USB
I try copying virtual machine folder to external USB suddenly some thing happens due to some connection error or wire being loose I loose all the connectivity to
the USB hard disk.
Now I have following screenshot
[image: an unexpected error is keeping you from copying the file]

I restart copy operation
[image: backup taking 4 hours]

Again I get to copy and it tells it may take another 4 hours to copy like this I keep getting this kind of situation.
I frequently keep taking backups. Is there an easy way that can reduce my time to take backup from 4 hours to less time
each time when I take backup on external USB.

The hard disk I fear I may loose because I frequently take backups and one day it will stop working because of so much read write operations happening.

376 Gb backup takes 4 hours to copy to USB

The hard disk being used to take backup can be seen here
https://www.amazon.in/Toshiba-Canvio-Basic-External-Drive/dp/B07DNDLHH8/ref=cm_cr_srp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8

Comment: I am using Toshiba hard disk I suppose it is usb3 but I am not sure now looking at the screenshots so how can I verify this is there any setting in Windows that can let me know what version of USB 2  or 3 I am using .

Comment: 376 Gb backup takes 4 hours to copy to USB

Comment: this is my hard disk https://www.amazon.in/Toshiba-Canvio-Basic-External-Drive/dp/B07DNDLHH8/ref=cm_cr_srp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8

Comment: I don't have a another computer to take backup is there some place where I can take backup online free.

Comment: I am an unemployed geek money is a big problem for me.

Comment: Are any of the files you are trying to backup over the size of 4.5GB, if so, then you are not able to backup them to a 32-bit (MBR) format which may be why you have the error in the 1st photo you published. With a 15.6Gb file a NTFS or exFat format, is used. 15.6Gb is too large for a 32-bit format. I'm just guessing you have multiple partitions on that very large hard disk, and alot of people try to use 32-bit after partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all.. the HDD drive you are using does not have an  [expected lifespan](https://www.compuram.de/blog/en/the-life-span-of-a-ssd-how-long-does-it-last-and-what-can-be-done-to-take-care/)  like an SSD drive does. I am not saying that it will never die but I am saying that they typically last a long LONG time.  My experience has been that the size will be considered tiny LONG before the drive wears out.

My point?  Don't worry about wearing that drive out as long as you treat the USB ports well and don't bang it around.

***As far as the speed:***

- Make sure you have write caching enabled for that drive.
- Make ***sure*** you are plugged into a USB 3.x port.  Most laptops have both USB2 and USB3 ports.

[This](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21904-enable-disable-disk-write-caching-windows-10-a.html)  will show you how to ensure that write caching is enabled.

IMHO, some machines simply have crappy USB  3 support.  The work machine I am on right now craps out when transferring large amounts of information over USB 3 but my home machine (which is a different brand) does not.  These both have nearly identical specs for proc and ram.